# How to make Context work in React using Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript

I'm trying to set up a context provider for my Next.js application, in Typescript.

I've set up a context provider before in React in plain JS, so this is my shot at learning TS.

In the code below, the `value={}` prop of `Context.Provider` returns the error:

`Property 'tasks' is missing in type '(State | Dispatch<SetStateAction<State>>)[]' but required in type 'State'`

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";
import { ReactNode } from "react";

interface Task {
    name: string,
    finished: boolean
}

interface State {
    tasks: Task[]
}

const initialState: State = {
    tasks: []
}

export const Context = createContext<State>(initialState)

type stateProps = {
    children: ReactNode
}
const StateContext = ({ children }: stateProps) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState<State>(initialState)

    return (
        <Context.Provider value={[state, setState]}>
            {children}
        </Context.Provider>
    )
}

export default StateContext;
```

For some reason, it's saying that `tasks` is missing in something that has the type `(State | Dispatch<SetStateAction<State>>)[]`, I have no clue where.

I've ran into lots of other issues while learning TS, but for some reason I can't figure this one out. Any ideas?

Comment: You've said that your context value is the type `State`, which is an object with a key of `tasks`, but then you set the value of your context to an array of `[state, setState]`, which has no `tasks` key on it. Make sure you have your editor set up properly to show typescript errors inline with your code.

Comment: Hi @AndyRay, please see my reply to Brietsparks. I do have the VScode extension installed, that's where I get the error message from.

Answer (score 1):

The `value` must be the same shape as the type specified in `createContext`, which is `State` in this case.

Your `useState` already holds a `State`, so just pass it directly to `value`

```
const [state, setState] = useState<State>(initialState)

return (
    <Context.Provider value={state}>
```

If your context needs to expose a setter, then change your `State` shape to include one

```
interface State {
    tasks: Task[]
    setTasks: (tasks: Task[]) => void
}
```

`initialState` might need a placeholder for that setter in order to satisfy the type checker

```
const initialState: State = {
    tasks: []
    setTasks: () => {}
}
```

Then, you can pass a setter into the `value` like you originally intended

```
    const [state, setState] = useState<State>(initialState)

    // might need to memoize this
    const value = {
      tasks: state,
      setTasks: (t: Tasks[]) => setState(t)
    }

    return (
        <Context.Provider value={value}>
```

The alternative to a placeholder for the setter is to make the context optional.

```
export const Context = createContext<State|undefined>();
```

Then, `initialState` and the placeholder setter are unneeded.

However, you will need to check the return value of `useContent(Context)` because it might be undefined.

You can put this check in a hook

```
function useStateContext() {
  const value = useContext(Context)
  if (!value) {
    throw new Error('state context has not been set yet')
  }
  return value;
}
```

And then use the hook in your components

Comment: Hi @brietsparks, in that case, how do I make use of the `setState` function within other components? If I only pass `state`? I used `value={[state, setState]}` so that I'm able to do `const [state, setState] = useContext(Context);` in other components. This is how I learned context in plain JS.

Comment: I see your updated answer, thank you for your help. Is this common, to declare a type for the setter? Someone just said to me: `You'd have to change the type of your context to include a setter. However it's going to be difficult to provide a default value for that case, so the common thing to do is to make the context optional... but then you'll need to check if it's provided before using it.`

Comment: @hans see my edits. I explained a way to do optional context

Comment: @hans Optional contexts are IMO a bad design. FYI a better type signature for the setter would be `React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<State>>`. That way it can also accept the [functional version](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)